# Lambda equivalent for List<?> compare using property A and return property B

Tags: java, java-8

```
private Date findRecordDate(List<DividendEvent> events, Scheme scheme) {
        for (DividendEvent event : events) {
            if (scheme.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(event.getScheme().getName())) {
                return event.getRecordDate();
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

Any suggestions on what would be the lambda equivalent for the code above?

Comment: It's an aside, but since you can use Java 8, you can use the modern Java date and time classes and should not bother with the outdated `Date` class. Even if you cannot modify `DividendEvant`, you can still use `Date.toInstant()` and return a modern `Instant` from your method, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll first need to filter the list then map it and then you can retrieve the first occurrence.

```
private Date findRecordDate(List<DividendEvent> events, Scheme scheme) {
        String name = scheme.getName();
        return events.stream().filter(e -> name.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getScheme().getName()))
                              .map(Di‌​videndEvent::getReco‌​rdDate) 
                              .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 100% clear, is there any advantage in this use-case for using Java8 Feature?

Comment: @JigarNaik using the latest Java features is not always the solution to a problem, but in most cases, they can optimize your code. a short example is within your code you're returning `null` and this can cause potential NullPointerExeptions therefore using `Optional#orElse` would solve that problem (because of java-8) and also with lazy-evaluation your code can once again be optimized and many more good features. It might be a good idea to have a read on java-8 features and their advantages.

Comment: You might have seen my earlier deleted comment about possible mistake with call to `.get()`, and edited, but now it's still not right I think. You cannot call `getRecordDate()` on the Optional... Maybe something like `.map(DividendEvent::getRecordDate).findFirst().orElse(null)`? In short, filter then map then findFirst then orElse.

Comment: `double dividend = schemeEventMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().getName().equals(schemeName))
     .findFirst().get().getValue().getDivAmount()` Is it possible to use `Optional#orElse` in `Map<Scheme, DividendEvent>` ?

Comment: I'm afraid what you wrote is same as previous version of answer, and that would throw exception if Optional is not present.

Comment: Either i have to handle `NoSuchElementException` or have to put null check in case i use `.map(DividendEvent::getRecordDate).findFirst().orElse(null)`

Comment: Let's try another way, maybe I'm mistaken. @JigarNaik, does the current version of the code in answer actually compile?

Comment: `Date recordDate = events.stream().filter(e -> schemeName.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getScheme().getName())).map(DividendEvent::getRecordDate)
     .findFirst().orElse(null);` This is the current version and it does compiles.

Comment: Since `findFirst()` returns an `Optional`, you may take the full consequence and use `.findFirst().map(e -> e.getRecordDate())` to return an `Optional<Date>`. If you really prefer to return `null` on not-found, then `.findFirst().map(e -> e.getRecordDate()).orElse(null)`.

Comment: @JigarNaik you pasted my suggestion, yes, it does compile... I meant the current version in answer. There, I still see `.findFirst().getRecordDate()`, which cannot compile. I'm confused. Is there a cache issue? (tried with 2 browsers)

Comment: @HuguesMoreau no it doesn't compile. findFirst().get() is missing.

Comment: Finally, 3rd revision is correct :) [Online runnable snippet](https://ideone.com/gZEaCn), try to uncomment the other revisions, you'll get the compile errors.